# Android 9-patch too many columns and rows?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, nine-patch

I am trying to use a 9-patch as background for a TextView, but it is treated as normal image file. According to the 9-Patch tool and the Intellij IDEA Layout Preview it should stretch properly though. 
I am using other 9-patches as well, so the problem can't be due to a misconfiguration of my system (e.g. missing library like in another case).

Checklist of what I've done so far:

- made sure the 9-patch perimeter contains only fully transparent or solid black pixels.
- file-ending is *.9.png
- tried it with and without specifying padding in the image

[Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/96/timeline9.png/) is the image I'd like to use.

Just now I saw the IDE throwing this "information" at me:
"ERROR: 9-patch image ...\res\drawable\timeline.9.png malformed.
       Too many rows and columns in 9-patch perimeter."

Are there any restrictions on the 9-patch I am not aware of? Tried searching the documentation for more information about that, but without success.

Thanks in advance,
/me

P.S.: I know the image could be optimized by removing the extra space within the segments, but that's sth. I planned on doing once it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 horizontal markers I was able to use 12 vertical markers (adding one more vertical or horizontal marker will give that error). So I think it counts the intersection (H * V), maximum might be 25 based on other answers.

---

**Update:**

Based on android code:

```
// Make sure the amount of rows and columns will fit in the number of
// colors we can use in the 9-patch format.
if (numRows * numCols > 0x7F) {
    errorMsg = "Too many rows and columns in 9-patch perimeter";
    goto getout;
}
```

The maximum value is 0x7F = 127.

A vertical marker is considered as one column, while horizontal marker is one row. so if you have 5 markers in each then it means you have **5 stretchable** columns + **6 un-stretchable** columns (the areas between the markers) so total of 11 vertical and same for horizontal so 11 * 11 = 121 which is less than 127 so you are good

in my case i had 12 vertical (12+13 =25) and 2 horizontal (2+3 =5) so 25*5=125 still less than 127.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the text area on your 9-patch. Define it at the bottom and the right of your picture.

Comment: As I've said, I've tried it with and without specifiying the padding area ( = text area) and according to the documentation is that optional.

Comment: Then if the problem comes really from the fact you have too many rows and columns, couldn't you try to cut your image in may parts? One part at left, one part at right and one part, repeated many times, in the middle?

Comment: I thought about this solution as well, but was hoping there is a way to avoid it, since I am using the image as background for a Textview, which spans the whole width of the screen and I doubt there is a way to properly concatinate multiple 9-patches.

Comment: Guess there is no way around it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked:

A maximum of 5 padding markers can be used.
A maximum of 5 scaling markers can be used as well.

(Update: Looks like it might be possible to go above this value. See the additional comment below.)

Comment: I am currently using a 9-patch with 12 scaling markers without a problem. So the limit lies somewhere between 12-24 (my guess would be 20) markers.

Btw, you've got a quite nice blog, Richard. Keep it up! :)

Comment: Thank you for the update marker count. Last time I checked, I was not able to go above 5. Could this be API level specific? Appreciate the kind feedback :)

Comment: On my Nexus 4 running 4.2.2 I can have 25 patches (5 horizontal and 5 vertical markers).

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my project, 18 vertical and 6 horizontal markers, returned a warning too many rows and columns. Then I used 18 vertical and 1 horizontal markers, it was good:), I guess it would be no more than 20.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the limit too.  Building against API 17.  I have a grid that has a column for each hour of the day and 4 rows.  I played around a bit and I think the constraint is on the number of patch intersections.  So if I had just one horizontal patch I made it to around 20 vertical patches before I hit the limit but if I had two horizontal patches I probably only made it to 10 vertical patches.  I tried removing the horizontal patch but then you get an error "No marked region found along edge".  HOWEVER, if I gave up resizing the height and selected the entire edge as a horizontal patch, I could add all 24 of my vertical patches.  I'd guess you'd maybe get to 40 if you left either the entire width or height resizable?  Just an educated guess based on the pattern I noticed.